# PyCharm | git pre-commit hook for inserting last change date causes that the file will be flagged as edited (which is the case). Workaround?

Tags: python, git, ide, pycharm, hook

I tried to use a git pre-commit hook for inserting informationen about the datetime of the last change to each commited file. The script works fine, but...

It seems that PyCharm resets the 'file-has-been-changed-flag' **before** the git hook executes. Therefore the inserting of the last-checkin-timestamp causes that the file shows up in PyCharms 'local changes'-list again and again (with the only change of the timestamp...)

Does anyone know about a workaround?

Thanks in advance.